# AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect' (PyGame)

Tags: python, pygame

I made a class called *Player*. I managed to show it on the screen(as a paddle), but when I'm trying to move it(pressing down arrow on keyboard), game crashes and I'm left with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "C:/Users/Optimus/Desktop/PongGame.py", line 37, in
>
> player.controlkeys()   File "C:/Users/Optimus/Desktop/PongGame.py", line 23, in controlkeys
>
> self.rect.move_ip(-50, 0) AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect'

Code(of class):

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerpaddle = pygame.rect.Rect((40,350,35,100))

    def controlkeys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-50, 0)

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.draw = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, self.playerpaddle)

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    player = Player()
    player.draw(screen)
    player.controlkeys()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/inwVgcsk.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Player** object has only one attribute that you defined: **playerpaddle**.  There is no element **rect**.  However, note that **playerpaddle** is of type **Rect**.  I suspect that what you want is something like

```
self.playerpaddle.move_ip(-50, 0)
```

You're not trying to move a particular rectangle -- *that* object will have the attributes of class **Rect**.

Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: Yeah, now it didn't crash :) Still, rectangle won't move. Gonna play with it tommorow - thanks for help.

Comment: Put in some nice tracing **print** statements to prove you're getting to the move command?

Comment: I put some `print`. `print` works, text is displayed in console everytime I'm holding arrow key but rectangle still don't move.

Comment: Okay -- that's progress.  What else have you tried?  Can you make this rectangle move at all?  Can you make any other rectangle move?  Any other object?  Do you get to movement parts of the code you call?

Comment: I made mistake like 
```self.rect_move_ip(-self.speed, 0)``` instead of adding dot operator after rect